# Apply a formula for different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, worksheet

I have an issue, I want to apply a formula on my main workbook with values from different sheets. The problem is the workbook used is monthly and the name changes. I was thinking of renaming the first sheet as "Sheet1" and apply the formula generally for Sheet 1.

```
    Function AlreadyOpen(sFname As String) As Boolean
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wkb = Workbooks(sFname)
    AlreadyOpen = Not wkb Is Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
End Function

Sub ianuarie()

'ianuarie
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("d:\LocalData\pw02353\Desktop\SDA si raport lunar\SDA ianuarie.xlsx")
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    If AlreadyOpen("Estimation & Effort Tracking_SCAR_PE-S&P_DVO_2019.xlsx") Then
    Else
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("d:\LocalData\pw02353\Desktop\SDA si raport lunar\Estimation & Effort Tracking_SCAR_PE-S&P_DVO_2019.xlsx")
    End If
    Workbooks("Estimation & Effort Tracking_SCAR_PE-S&P_DVO_2019.xlsx").Activate
    Range("U2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF('[SDA ianuarie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2,RC[-18],'[SDA ianuarie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C6)"
    Range("U2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("U2:U66"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        Range("U2:U66").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-78
    Range("U2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Option Explicit

Sub MonthTest() Dim strMonth As String

strMonth = InputBox("Introduceti luna", "Raport lunar", "ianuarie")

If strMonth = "ianuarie" Then
    Call ianuarie
    MsgBox "Ati selectat raportul pe luna ianuarie" ElseIf strMonth = "februarie" Then
    Call februarie
    MsgBox "Ati selectat raportul pe luna februarie"....and so on for each month
```

I need to refer to a general "Sheet 1" if I have the workbook opened, only to substract and calculate the values based on it.

Comment: 1) Does the workbook containing the values have only one sheet? 2) Does the name of the workbook changes monthly? if so, what name does it have? 3) Do you open the workbook manually or with vba code?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz 1) The workbook im trying to complete has multiple sheets ; 2) The workbook I'm retrieving data from is changin the name monthly "X March" "X April" "X May", I was thinking about using a Wild card, but I can't figure it out. 3) I open the workbooks manually, I think it is easier the build up the code, so I will open the file I'm completing and also the file I'm retrieving data (X Month) from in order to complete the main file. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It'd help if you edit your question and add print screens of how the data is structured in each file (main and monthly)
In the meanwhiile, confirm if this structure is correct:
April Workbook -> Sheet 1 -> Main workbook
May Workbook -> Sheet 1 -> Main workbook
Questions: 1) do you want to make a conditional sum values from Sheet 1 in each monthly file? (Your code shows a sum, but you said "subtract and calculate values"

Comment: So, my main workbook contains some categories and has to be update monthly. Meanwhile, my monthly report contains those categories and I have to extract and sum some of them and for this I am using SUMIF. Answering your question: 1) Yes, I want to use a SUMIF in order to retrieve and sum up each activity on categories and yes, in the monthly workbooks there is some kind of the same template, I have to =SUMIF(the first column that is in the monthly, a criteria that is present in my main workbook;the last column that is in the monthly report)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

You can do it pretty quick with find and replace:

Press Ctrl + F, go to the replace tab. In the "Find" field you can put "Sheet1" and in the "Replace" field type the name of the new sheet you want to refer.

N.B. You have to open the Options menu and choose "Formulas" in the "Look in" drop-down menu.

Method 2:

You can use the INDIRECT function. More on it:
https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-worksheet-reference

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use a macro in order to calculate some data retrieved from a monthly report, but in a main workbook. Let's name the main workbook ABC and the monthly reports "X March", "X May" and so on. I need to complete periodically ABC with data calculated from "X March" in a month, from "Y May" in another month and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this structure:

Main workbook:

[image: Main workbook]

May workbook:

[image: May workbook]

June workbook:

[image: June workbook]

Currently the formulas sum based on the workbooks monthly names.

What you want is VBA code that adds the new month to the formula?

Adds Jul:

```
SUMIFS([SumExternalJulWorkbook.xlsm]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$5;[SumExternalJuLWorkbook.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5;A2)
```

Comment: I have splitted the code in months, to calculate them for each month and edited the code above. Also, I have created a separate one to call each month when inputed. The only issue is that when I input the month, it opens only the Monthly Report Excel file (SDA ianuarie), but not the main Excel file too (Estimation & Effort Tracking_SCAR_PE-S&P_DVO_2019.xlsx).

Comment: The weird thing is when I run the code line by line starting with the code that calls my subs, it works.